# Why do lithium batteries vary so much in price?

Tags: lithium-ion

Ok my actual problem has to do with 2 specific products that are confusing me. So for my camper I’m looking into a 12v 100ah lithium ion LiFeP04 battery and they’re about 850-950 USD [link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XX197GJ) Why does this 100ah cost 950 yet this solar battery pack with 24000mAh costs 40 [link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07C24XC2L). That would mean 4 of these tiny battery packs (24ah) hold the same ah as the battle born beast that’s 950 usd. What am I missing here? If anyone could answer this stupid question I have I would immensely appreciate it!

Comment: This has got nothing to do with EE and everything to do with the shambles of products amazon offer including the same product in different places at different prices, product quality ignorance, no clear data on what you are buying etc... I'm voting to close this question as not relevant for this site. If you want to get to the bottom of it, buy both then write a blog describing the technical differences vs cost differences because nobody will do it via this site.

Comment: You are comparing a 12 V 100 Ah = 1200 Wh battery with a 3.7 V 24 Ah (claimed) = 89 Wh one. That’s a 13 fold difference.

Comment: The solar cell battery doesn't state its battery voltage explicitly so we have to assume it is only **one** cell in series (that's what almost all of these products have so that they can be charged from 5 V with a very simple charging circuit (one that doesn't need to boost the voltage). So what winny states is very likely correct. The other battery 1) is a completely different chemistry 2) does state the real battery voltage 3) comes with a proper datasheet with specifications that are **real**. **You're comparing apples to walnuts!** To draw conclusions, compare similar products.

Comment: Tip: 'A' for ampere. 'V' for volt. Capitals matter.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. "for my camper I’m looking into a 12v ... lithium ion ... battery"  Why? A quick look at other Amazon prices shows a Li ion battery is 4~5 x the cost of a deep cycle (leisure) lead acid battery. If you will personally carry this battery, e.g. for backpacking, then the extra cost for reduced weight would be useful but if your camper van will be taking the weight why pay the extra cost? (Note this application does need a deep cycle battery, not an ordinary (cheaper) car battery.)

Comment: @GrahamNye depending on the camper space constraints and usage pattern, one may pretty well want Li-ion battery instead of lead-acid. I considered one myself, but I don't have enough leisure time in order to get the advantages.

Comment: @fraxinus The two types seem to be around the same size. One LiFePO4 battery vendor does claim the following [advantages](https://www.roadpro.co.uk/lithium-battery-guide) which could offset the much higher price if realised.

Comment: @GrahamNye the same size, yeah... but this is some exotic configuration made to fit 100Ah car battery bay. The usual 100Ah 12V LiFePO4 is less than half that. https://shop.gwl.eu/LiFePO4-12V-packs/GBS-LiFePO4-High-Power-battery-pack-12V-100Ah.html#tab2 And, for a cycle use, one can safely use at most 30%-40% of the capacity of Pb-acid. So 100Ah lead-acid battery is really 40Ah with some spare (almost single use) capacity. And then, the weigth - ~30kg for nominal 100Ah Pb vs 10kg for real 100Ah LiFePO

Answer (score 2):

The 100Ah battery from your question has 4 cells in series, each one having 100Ah capacity working at or around 3V. This makes a 100Ah, 12V battery that can hold 1200Wh (watt-hours) of energy. It is the energy that makes the price (and mass, and volume) of a battery. You get ~0.8 USD per watt-hour.

Rather on the expensive side, but still normal (at least here in EU, you can get comparable product for ~5 USD per ampere-hour at 12V).

The 24Ah battery is (persumably) single cell of 24Ah (or multiple cells in parallel that are together 24Ah). Its working voltage is like 3.7V (the chemistry is slightly different from the above). It holds 24 * 3.7 = 88.8 Wh for USD 40.00 or like 0.45 USD per watt-hour. Cheaper than the above, but probably pretty much low-grade (both in cycle life and safety) and/or less than the advertized capacity.

And, assuming they are of the same quality, to get them comparable to the first battery, you will need not 4, but rather 12 of them ($480) and it will be up to you to get a sane battery management (probably another $100-$250) and mount and connect them safely (whatever $$$). And because of the different chemistry, they will never be as safe as LiFePO4.